# Marginal/Conditional odd ratios - collapsibility

Tags: regression, logistic, causality, confounding

I have fitted a logistic regression model to some individual binary data. I am mostly interested in the causal effect of a particular binary variable (A), and so I estimated the marginal odds ratio comparing 1.A to 0.A. And let's say the estimated marginal odds ratio was 1.2. Now if I go on to calculate the conditional odds ratio, i.e. by conditioning on A=0 and then estimating the odds and doing the same for A=1, and then finding the ratio between the two, what I got is around 1.4 (for example). How do I interpret such a difference? Is this to do with collapsibility since I am comparing marginal odds ratio with conditional odds ratio? What I struggle with is that so far what I have learnt about collapsibility is that marginal and conditional odds ratio might differ even if there is no real confounding by a second variable B, but in this case we are not conditioning on any potential confounders. Essentially, I think what I am comparing are $P(Y=1|do(A=1))P(Y=0|do(A=0))/P(Y=1|do(A=0))P(Y=0|do(A=1))$ with $P(Y=1|A=1)P(Y=0|A=0)/P(Y=1|A=0)P(Y=0|A=1)$.

What follows is that I also estimated the marginal predicted probability for A=0 (say 0.6) and compare this with the observed "prevalence" in the A=0 subgroup (say 0.55). How can I interpret their difference?

Comment: The basic definition of causality is that $A$ causes $Y$ if $P(Y|\operatorname{do}(A))>P(Y).$ Why not just do that comparison?